# Applying dominated convergence theorem on sum of random variables and indicator

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider i.i.d random variables $(X_k) \in \mathbb{N}$ and Y$_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\mu= E(X_i)<1 $

Consider $E[(1-\frac{Y_n}{n} )1_{\{k \leq Y_n \leq n\}}]$ with $k \in [0, n]$
How can I apply dominated convergence to conculde that this expression goes to $1- \mu$

Why do I need the indicator here?

Comment: Is $k$ just a constant number here? I don't understand it. And are the random variables $X_n$ non negative? Because you only mentioned that their common expectation is less than $1$, but is it also positive?

Comment: @Mark : The $X_n$ take values in the naturals.  As explained in ISO 80000-2, the naturals are the nonnegative integers, so no $X_n$ is negative.

Comment: The assumption $k \in [0,n]$ is confusing. It seems to indicate that $k$ can depend on $n$ in which case the result is false: Take $k=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since the $X_n$ are taking values in $\mathbb{N}$ we conclude that $0<\mu<1$.

The strong law of large numbers tells us that $1-\frac{Y_n}{n}\to 1-\mu$ almost surely. Also, let's take a look at the event $\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}=\{\frac{k}{n}\leq \frac{Y_n}{n}\leq 1\}$. If $\omega$ is some point where $\frac{Y_n(\omega)}{n}\to \mu$ (from the strong law it happens at almost every $\omega$) then the condition $0<\mu<1$ implies that we eventually have $\frac{k}{n}\leq\frac{Y_n(\omega)}{n}\leq 1$, or equivalently $1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}(\omega)=1$ for every large enough $n$. So for such $\omega$ we have $1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}\to 1$. We conclude that:

$(1-\frac{Y_n}{n})1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}\to 1-\mu$ almost surely

Also, note that for every $n$ we have:

$0\leq(1-\frac{Y_n}{n})1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}\leq (1-\frac{k}{n})\leq 1$

So this allows us to use the dominated convergence theorem. We wouldn't be able to get that bound without the indicator. We indeed have $1-\frac{Y_n}{n}\to 1-\mu$ almost surely, but without the indicator we wouldn't be able to find a uniform bound on the sequence to use DCT.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer. Why can't I state that $\mu$ could be 0, if I look at your first line.

Comment: But do we need DCT here? We know from strong law of large numbers that we covergence to $ 1-\mu$?

Comment: Well, the expectation of a nonnegative random variable $X$ is $0$ if and only if $X=0$ almost surely. But here you say the $X_i$ are natural valued, so as I understand they are never equal to $0$. But anyway, if they are just non negative and $\mu=0$ then they are $0$ almost surely. In that case all the $Y_n$ are almost surely $0$, so then we can just compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[(1-\frac{Y_n}{n})1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}$ directly. (it is just a constant sequence)

Comment: Using the strong law of large numbers we concluded that $(1-\frac{Y_n}{n})1_{\{k\leq Y_n\leq n\}}$ converges to $1-\mu$ almost surely. But in general it doesn't imply that the sequence of expectations converges to the expectation of the constant random variable $1-\mu$. In order to interchange between limit and expectation we usually have to use a theorem from analysis which allows to do that: monotone convergence or DCT.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. You made everything absolute clear to me. I appreciate your help:)